# Invoking a EJB from PHP

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, jmx

Is there any easy way to invoke a RMI method on a EJB from PHP? We have a java app and a PHP app that sometimes needs to talk to it. What we do now is have a java binary that PHP invokes when it needs to do something, but I would love to know if there is a way to do this directly from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979499/how-to-call-a-ejb-session-bean-from-php) helps you out. i'm facing the same problem at the moment and finally i decidet to do all i need via [SOAP](https://www.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapclient.php), using a java-webservise as server and the soap-client in php.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options to tightly (or loosely) integrate PHP and Java. There are 2 PHP-Java bridge solutions out there. One open source, the other by Zend.
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Alternatively, there is a product called Quercus which actually runs your PHP code in Java. You can then call anything that java can from inside PHP as if it was a native function. Quercus doesn't support ALL PHP functions and commands, but you can run WordPress under without changes.
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/